# How to exclude the floats from the factorial method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, recursion

When finding factorial, using recursion(Ruby), following code finds the factorial of the whole numbers but fails in cases of floats. How can I tweak this?
I thought about using domains like in Maths but I do not know how to do that, yet.

```
def factorial num
  if num < 0
    return "Please provide a whole number."
  end

  if num <=1
    1
  else
    num * factorial(num-1)
  end

end
```

Comment: The short answer is that factorials are only defined for non-negative integers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: @jtbandes, what's your point?

Comment: @jtbandes I know that, I wanted a way to filter out float inputs.

Comment: Ah, then replace the first three lines with `return "Please provide a non-negative integer" unless n.class == Fixnum && n >= 0`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Please, no. Never check for the class. Use `kind_of?` / `is_a?` instead. What if I want to subclass `Fixnum`? (Well, in this specific case, subclassing `Fixnum`) is not allowed, but for other classes that is not necessarily true. Oh, and also: please, never use `Fixnum`. It has never been part of the spec, it is only there as a compiler optimization which should never have been exposed to the programmer. And in fact, in YARV 2.4, it *will* only be a compiler optimization and there will be no more `Fixnum` and `Bignum`, the same way it already works today with flonums.

Comment: The `Fixnum` and `Bignum` constants will be aliased to `Integer` for a transitional period, but someday, they will be gone.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, ah, yes. I've made that mistake before. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to filter out floats is to use what makes them float :)
They are not completely divisible by 1.

```
def factorial num
  if (num % 1 != 0 || num < 0)
    return "Please provide a whole number."
  end

  if num <=1
    1
  else
    num * factorial(num-1)
  end
end
```

Hope that helps. Cheers

Comment: By the way instead of second if statement you can write:

Comment: return 1 if (0..1).include? num
num * factorial(num-1)        
Cheers

Comment: Uh, a method that sometimes returns `String`s and sometimes returns `Integer`s looks highly suspect.

Answer (score 0):

While @CarySwoveland correctly pointed out that in mathematics, the 'factorial' operation is only defined for natural numbers, a generalization to real numbers exists under the name "gamma function". gamma(n) equals n! for natural numbers n.

[UPDATE: As @JörgWMittag explained, it's not gamma(n), but gamma(n+1) which equals n!]

The gamma function is available in Ruby ([see here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Math.html#method-c-gamma)), and you could invoke it for non-natural numbers.

However, you need to be aware that your factorial function will then have the somewhat unusual property, that it will return sometimes a Fixnum and sometimes a Float.

Comment: Γ(n) is not n!, it's (n-1)!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has certain type conversion protocols that could be useful here. In particular, any object that wants to act as an `Integer` should respond to `to_int`. So, you could just try to convert your input to an `Integer`, and Ruby will take care of the rest:

```
def factorial(num)
  num = num.to_int
  # … carry on normally
end
```

This way, anything that wants to behave as an `Integer` can be passed here, and anything that doesn't, will `raise` a `NoMethodError`.

If you want to be *really* nice, you could `rescue` from that `NoMethodError` and `raise` your own `TypeError` with a descriptive message. But usually, any Ruby programmer understands the type conversion protocols and that a `NoMethodError` for `to_int` means that you passed something which is not `Integer`-like to a method that expects an `Integer`-like object.